# Can I scrape StackOverflow job postings for research purpose?

Tags: web-crawler, scrape, stackexchange

I am thinking of scraping StackoOverflow job postings for my research.

In specific, I am going to construct the network, where nodes are 'industry and technology' tagged to the job postings.

This research is not for the personal practice, but for the publication of journal papers.

Here, I want to know whether 
1) it is possible to scrape StackoOverflow job postings for the research purpose.
2) if possible, is there a way to scrape job postings in the past
3) other database that provides job postings.

Comment: You can scrape anything, just it really depends if StackoOverflow  if protected from scraping and if so, how hard.
It can go from simply just  rotating between proxies to using captcha solving service to scrape any website

Comment: @DevyDev please consider common web scraping rules and gentlemen agreements.. https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt

Comment: @Jonas I do understand, just saying same as you posted, its possible to do

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem so, since `/jobs/` is restricted from scraping.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt

So to make a long story short, you are **not allowed** to, but technically you could. 
Be smart and follow the gentlemen agreement.